# How to get location as a user input?

Tags: html, forms, google-maps

Need to create a php form and there one field is to get the user location through a pointer. I used this javascript code.

```
function myMap() {
     var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(7.645597492221576,80.08565722656249);
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
      var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 8};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        draggable:true,
       // animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
       //console.log(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
       document.getElementById('latitude').value=event.latLng.lat();
       document.getElementById('longitude').value=event.latLng.lng();
    });

}
```

Now I need to pass this to my controller How do I passed this values to my controller?

Comment: have you read the documentation for google maps? Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: Could you be more clear ? Google maps has it's own API, so you need look at Google Maps JS API.

Comment: could you please tell me which part do I need to refer to take user input location from google map and send it to mysql table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ About SQL field format - you need to store your coordinates in POINT type

Comment: how to take the lat and lang from html form ? I am stuck there I cannot understand how to get it.

Comment: You can't get lat and long from html form. You can get it from markers coordinates. If wana get lat and long from user address, obviously you need  Google coder. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse. There are many examples